# querySkuDetailsAsync callback never called

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api, play-billing-library

I think to have followed all the steps correctly from the documentation but I can't reach the callback of querySkuDetailsAsync, no errors reported. The app is working correctly with IAB, now I'm only migrating from old library to the new 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3' but many problems.
Another question, in the new library is also necessary the use of License Key from Play Console? I don't find documentation about using that in the new library.

I can correctly and without errors reach this line `billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, (billingResult2, skuDetailsList) ->`

Sku ids are correctly

```
    private void setupIab()
    {
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(getApplicationContext()).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult)
            {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
                {
                    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<> ();
                    skuList.add("test_sku_1");
                    SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP).build();

                    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, (billingResult2, skuDetailsList) ->
                    {
                        // Process the result.
                        if (billingResult2.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null)
                        {
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected()
            {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }
        });
    }
```

Best regards

Comment: need log in querySkuDetailsAsync

Comment: @GMG: how did you fix this issue? I am now trying to update from v2 to v3, and I have the exact same problem. I could connect to the billing service; however, `querySkuDetailsAsync` callback is never called. I don't get any errors either.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct form me and is similar to what I use, but I do not call `querySkuDetailsAsync` within `onBillingSetupFinished`, I call it only when the user buy something.

Maybe when `onBillingSetupFinished` runs, the setup is not really finished yet, you could try using this, so it will be called just later:

```
 if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        new Handler().post(() -> {
            List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
            skuList.add("test_sku_1");
            SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP).build();

            billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, (billingResult2, skuDetailsList) ->
            {
                // Process the result.
                if (billingResult2.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just done in one of the many tests, but nothing, callbacks is never called

Comment: So I think that your problem is probably not related to the code but to the settings on the Google Play Console. Have you at least uploaded a release APK ?

Comment: Do you have multiple Google accounts on the testing  device?